# Jira -- export tempo timesheet (grid view) to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, export, jira

Jira:  How do you  export tempo timesheet (grid view) to Excel  -- either .csv or an ordinary excel file.

I am using Microsoft Edge browser, and there is no easy link available (such as Export).

I would like an option that did  NOT involve installing third-party tools.

I web-searched this, but the results do not apply to my situation.

I am using:  Jira v8.9.1 (Atlassian Jira )

Comment: Excel can sometimes parse HTML tables pretty well. What happens if you simply hit ctrl A in the browser (or drag and select the relevant data), then copy and paste in to excel? Alternatively paste in Notepad, then re-copy and paste in to excel.

Comment: Oh you can also try copy and pasting into Google Sheets. OR "import from web" straight from Excel  data ribbon. The latter provides a refreshable data source link, which is convenient for updates, but I am not sure how well it deals with log ins etc.

Comment: Do you need Power Query? https://chandoo.org/wp/import-web-data-power-query/#:~:text=Go%20to%20Power%20Query%20ribbon%20%26%20click%20on,will%20show%20up%20in%20the%20navigation%20tree%20structure.